# Failed to Install gem Install rails ERROR Could not find a valid gem 'rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ssl-certificate

**gem install rails -v 3.2.14**

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (=0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed
>   (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try install ruby with rbenv very easy to use and update:http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rbenv/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your machine is running on secure VPN. In my case I experienced same error whenever I try to install any gem while I am connected to secure VPN. Try to disconnect from VPN and try to install the rails gem again. 
 Hope it helps!!